# How to push in firebase cloud function transaction?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following struct:

```
{
  "point_logs": {
    "user1": {
      "LrDm-0OBBg84rTSXGyF": {
        "action": "action_type_1",
        "point": 1
      },
      "LrDm0b0oF-48EF3ZsqF": {
        "action": "action_type_2",
        "point": 1
      }
    },
    "user2": {
      "LrDm0dfZsEE40HvnwEc": {
        "action": "action_type_5",
        "point": 1
      },
      "LrDm0gKsdEw3O3ync_7": {
        "action": "redeem_1",
        "point": -2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am currently add a firebase cloud function to redeem point, since the cloud function is `async`, in order to make sure there is sufficient point to redeem, I need make redeem function atomic.

I tried use transaction:

```
exports.redeemPoints = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  db.ref('/point_logs/' + user_id).transaction((data) => {
    admin.database().ref('/points_assign_logs/' + user_id).once('value', (snapshot) => {
      // code to iterate and sum all points from this user's logs
      if (remain_points >= redeem_point) {
        admin.database().ref('/point_logs/' + user_id).push(redeem_log);
      }
      return data
    });
  });
});
```

But with multiple async call to this function, the remain point can be negative, even though there is a check `if (remain_points >= redeem_point)`.

How can I user transaction correctly to atomic this log update?

Comment: Your transaction looks useless here, what do you want to sum ?

Comment: ya, i feel useless too, the sum is to accumulate points from all logs. Maybe I should have total points filed, and transaction update that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your structure looks like

```
|
|__ points_logs
|       |___ $userId
|                |___ $logId
|                        |___ point
|___ points_assign_logs
        |___ $userId
```

And you want to increment points_assign_logs with the sum of point of each log of a user. I guess it should be something like that:

```
exports.redeemPoints = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  db.ref('/point_logs/' + user_id).once("value").then(data => {
    data.forEach(e => {
       admin.database().ref('/points_assign_logs/' + user_id).transaction(snap => {
          return (snap || 0) + e.val().point;
       });
    });
  });
});
```

Waiting your comeback !

Comment: Wow, your guess is accurate! Thank you! The only different part from your understanding is the point increment. The point is increased by insert another log, not update the existing `point` value. Thus, in this design, transaction will never work. I changed a bit the design. You can refer to my answer. Your idea about transaction is correct.

Answer (score 0):

*@Curse* provide correct answer for using transaction. But for my case, i need to change the json struction in order to use transaction. I just post out to share.

The idea of [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#transaction) is to

> Atomically modifies the data at this location.

I **cannot** apply transaction for **inserting** data. Thus, I added a new field to accumulate the `total_points` for each user:

```
|
|__ points_logs
|       |___ $userId
|                |___ $logId
|                |       |___ point
|                |___ $logId
|                |       |___ point
|                |___ $logId
|                |       |___ point
|                |
|                |___ $total_points
|___ points_assign_logs
        |___ $userId
```

Then I can user transaction over `total_points`:

```
db.ref('/points_logs/' + uid + '/total_points').transaction((total_points) => {
    return (total_points || 0) + new_point_val;
}, (error, committed, snapshot) => {
    // handle error, committed case
});
```